# Electrical - 50A to 20A Adapter for heater?

Tags: electrical, woodworking, 240v, workshop, detached-structure

I am currently in the process of remodeling my detached garage and have run into a snag with the electrical. The previous owner ran 6-2 wiring out to the garage into a 50A outlet but then pigtailed a 20A outlet off of that (see attached pictures). 
[image: Wiring - cover][image: Wiring - no cover]

I have a Cadet Garage Heater that needs the 6-20R outlet. The heater would only be used in the winter and when I am making something out in the garage which is not that frequent. I am assuming the pigtail connection the previous owner ran is not safe.

Ideally, I would run 6-3 wire out to the garage for a subpanel and come off of that but I am hoping for an easier solution in the form of an adapter. As mentioned before, the usage of the heater would be limited to the winter, running maybe 2-3 hours max a couple times a month. I would like to keep the 50A outlet in case I ever decide to flirt with a welder.

The 6-2 wiring is on a 50A breaker and is run underground to to the garage. Also ran out to the garage are two 14-2 lines as well as a 14-3 line. The two 14-2's are on a 15A breaker and the 14-3 is on another 15A breaker tied into a few things inside the house. I have already replaced the fluorescent lights with LED lights and added a couple more plugs off of the 14-2's. The 14-3 controls the lights on the garage (other switch is at the back door).

All help is appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could have a safe, code compliant install now if you used the 6/2 to feed a small subpanel with no neutral.  The 240V receptacles don't have a neutral.

There may be a tap rule that would allow you to tap the 50A circuit with #12 if you keep the tap very short, but only if you hardwired the heater, not with a receptacle.

Answer (score 0):

If the heater has a built-in breaker or fuse, then I would just make a cheater cord. Totally not legit, but it should be safe, provided the heater has its own breaker or fuse.

Comment: No, an adapter cord for plugging a 6-20 device into a 6-50 receptacle is *fine*

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Because it's not part of the building wiring, and thus out of the bailiwick of the electrical code?

Comment: @Harper -- partially, at least.

Comment: It's only fine if the heater has built-in protection to prevent overload of its wiring and cord. Otherwise, swapping in a 20 amp breaker like @EdBeal suggests is a better idea.

Comment: This is the heater that I have
https://cadetheat.com/products/garage-heaters/RCP402S

I would like to keep the 50A outlet in case I get a welder so really do not want to run new line although it may sound like I have to? Two winters ago, I used the heater for about 2 hours without incident with the current setup. Last year, I did not even use the heater.

Comment: Running a new line is not what Ed suggested. He is suggesting that you replace the 50 amp breaker with a 20 amp one, and replace the 50 amp receptacle with a 20 amp one. When you get a welder, you can put the 50 amp breaker and receptacle back.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the 50 amp breaker or add another 20 and remove the 50 amp outlet since this is not code . you can run the 20 amp circuit on the number 6 wire but may need to pigtail for the breaker. If you want to use for a welder at a later time you still have the breaker and outlet that can be reinstalled